# Angular click event not working, what gives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building a silly little calculator in an attempt to learn AngularJS.  I'm attempting to use ng-click trigger events to update the "screen" of my calculator.  Here's my code:

```css
var calcApp = angular.module('NodeCalc', []);
calcApp.controller('CalcController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.memory = {
    recall: function() {
      console.log('memory recall');
    },
    clear: function() {
      console.log('memory clear');
    },
    add: function(value) {
      console.log('memory add');
    }
  }
  $scope.buttons = {
    memory: [ 
      {text: 'mrc', action: $scope.memory.recall},
      {text: 'm-', action: $scope.memory.clear},
      {text: 'm+', action: $scope.memory.add},
    ]
  };
}]);
```

```html
<body ng-app="NodeCalc" ng-controller="CalcController">
  <form class="calc">
    <p class="calc-display">
      <input type="text" name="res" id="res" value="0" class="calc-display-input" onfocus="this.blur()">
    </p>
    <p class="calc-row">
      <button ng-repeat="button in buttons.memory" type="button" class="calc-button calc-button-gray" ng-click="{{button.action}}">{{button.text}}</button>
      <button type="button" class="calc-button calc-button-red calc-button-big" onclick="a('/')">/</button>
    </p>
```

So, I know it has to do with the way I'm attaching my memory functions to my scope object.  Can I not use scope in this way on the ng-click directive?  I'm not really sure how else to achieve my goal here.  The buttons render correctly, but I get a huge angular error-barf in my console related to:

> Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=2&p3=%7B%7Bbutton.action%7D%7D&p4=%7Bbutton.action%7D%7D

Comment: Perhaps you mean `ng-click="button.action()"`

Comment: I tried that.  I get the same stack trace, and it runs those functions without any clicks occuring...  I just realized that error is a link giving a little more information:
Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{button.action}}] starting at [{button.action}}].

Comment: did you try a literal function here `{text: 'mrc', action: function() { alert('hi'); }},`

Comment: Just tried - same thing.  So I just tried removing the brackets from around "button.action" in the HTML completely.  The error is gone, but no click events fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-click` expression should be **`ng-click="button.action()"`**

While using `ng-*` directive, one is not suppose to wrap it with *mustache*, passed expression will be parsed by `angular`

```js
var calcApp = angular.module('NodeCalc', []);
calcApp.controller('CalcController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {

    $scope.memory = {
      recall: function() {
        console.log('memory recall');
      },
      clear: function() {
        console.log('memory clear');
      },
      add: function(value) {
        console.log('memory add');
      }
    }
    $scope.buttons = {
      memory: [{
        text: 'mrc',
        action: $scope.memory.recall
      }, {
        text: 'm-',
        action: $scope.memory.clear
      }, {
        text: 'm+',
        action: $scope.memory.add
      }, ]
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="NodeCalc" ng-controller="CalcController">
  <form class="calc">
    <p class="calc-display">
      <input type="text" name="res" id="res" value="0" class="calc-display-input" onfocus="this.blur()">
    </p>
    <p class="calc-row">
      <button ng-repeat="button in buttons.memory" type="button" class="calc-button calc-button-gray" ng-click="button.action()">{{button.text}}</button>
      <button type="button" class="calc-button calc-button-red calc-button-big" onclick="alert('/')">/</button>
    </p>
```

Comment: Thank you!  That was what I was missing!

Comment: Glad you figured it out @SpacePope.  Can one of you two explain the answer for future readers?  The comments indicated that `ng-click="button.action()"` wasn't working.

Comment: @danh – What exactly is to be added ?

Comment: The problem was I tried `ng-click="{{button.action()}}"`.  Removing the brackets was the solution.

Comment: That's what confused me.   See the first two comments under the OP.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is just calling a function defined on `$scope` in the `ng-click` (the normal way) and passing the `$index` from the `ng-repeat`.

```
ng-click="clicked($index)"

$scope.clicked = function(index) {
    var fn = $scope.buttons.memory[index].action;
    fn();
}
```